# Just copying a xaml file into a clob. Why is not working

Tags: c#, xaml, clob

I need to copy the content of one.xaml file into a byte clob.  This is my code. It looks like I am not accessing the content of  this file.  Can anyone tell me why. I am new to C# APIs but I am a programmer. the choice of 4000 is because of the maximum string size restriction, just in case someone wonders.  I might have bugs about zies etc.. but the main thing is that I want to se the content of thje xaml file into the clob .  Thanks.

```
           string LoadedFileName = @"C:\temp2\one.xaml";//Fd.FileName;
             byte[] clobByteTotal ;
             FileStream stream = new FileStream(LoadedFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
             if (stream.Length % 2 >= 1)
             {
                  clobByteTotal = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
             }
             else clobByteTotal = new byte[stream.Length];
             for (int i = 0; i <= stream.Length/4000; i++)
             {   
                 int x = (stream.Length / 4000 == 0) ? (int)stream.Length : 4000;
                 stream.Read(stringSizeClob, i*4000, x);
                 String tempString1 = stringSizeClob.ToString();
                 byte[] clobByteSection = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringSizeClob.ToString());
                 Buffer.BlockCopy(clobByteSection, 0, clobByteTotal, i * clobByteSection.Length, clobByteSection.Length);
             }
```

Comment: There is **no such maximum string size restriction** of 4000 characters. You are probably referring to the restriction of string *literals'* length: an utterly different matter.

Comment: thank  you for the clarification and my c# enlightement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need read a content of a text file into a byte array, just can do this

```
string xamlText = File.ReadAlltext(LoadedFileName );
byte[] xamlBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xamlText); //if this is a Unicode and not UTF8

//write byte data somewhere
```

This much shorter option, which is suitable, naturally for not too big files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do y ou know a way for files longer than 4000 bytes?  I will try your answer right away but I still have the problem with larger than 4000 bytes.

Comment: @user1298925 where are you getting this magical 4000 byte limit for strings/arrays? I believe the limit on strings should be more like 2 GIGAbytes.. and if you exceed that, your design is definitely wrong.

Comment: @user1298925 see my comment on your question: **there is no such limit.**

Comment: That worked.  A BIG Thank you to @Tigran, Eatlz and Codesparkel.   I also learned about my misunderstanding of String size limit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)?

```
byte[] xamlBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Comment: in this case there is no difference. You want to read the contents of the file into a byte array, which means that you treat the file as a binary file, so this is completely OK. Or did I misunderstand the problem.